# Polymer determine the last item on dom-repeat items

Tags: javascript, data-binding, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to create breadcrumbs from an array of strings.
I have an array property called `taxonomy` and it looks like the `["categories", "clothing", "men", "suits"]`. Using `dom-repeat` like this:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{taxonomy}}" id="breadcrumbs">
  <span>{{item}}</span><span hidden$="[[computeSpanHidden]]"> > </span>
</template>
```

The resulting view looks like this:

**categories > clothing > men > suits >**

What i would like is to remove the last **>** to get something like this:

**categories > clothing > men > suits**

I have tried doing this by binding to the hidden attribute of the span i want to hide but I am stuck. The incomplete `computeSpanHidden` function looks like this:

```
computeSpanHidden: function(){
  if(this.taxonomy.slice(-1)[0] == /**the value i want to know how to get **/)
    { return true; } 
      else 
        { return false; }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to use `index` to determine. Read it more from [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#dom-repeat).

> index. The index of item in the array. (The index value changes if the
>   array is sorted or filtered)

```
<span>{{item}}</span><span hidden$="[[computeSpanHidden(taxonomy,index)]]"> > </span>

computeSpanHidden: function(taxonomy,index){
  return (taxonomy.length - 1) === index
}
```